# How to create a FIPS-capable OpenSSL in a Bitbake recipe?

Tags: openssl, yocto, bitbake, fips

**Main Question**

I need to create a FIPS-capable OpenSSL for my project. The OpenSSL FIPS object module is successfully cross-compiled and installed for my target platform. I can't seem to get the FIPS-capable library to point to it for its own compilation phase.

Does anyone know the appropriate flags to add to the `openssl_%.bbappend`?

---

**Extra Info**

I've tried many things at this point - many different flags with many different error output. I'm not certain what's related to my specific environment versus what could be considered a generic error, so I'll add info here if it becomes relevant / requested.

My openssl version is 1.0.2d and my FIPS version is 2.0.14.

Comment: When building the FIPS-capable OpenSSL library I believe you can use `--fipsdir` configure option to tell the FIPS-capable library where the FIPS Object Module is located. It is very similar to Autotools and Configure's `--libdir` flag.

Comment: That's one of the things I've tried. The command `./config fips --fipsdir=/my/path/to/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0` lands me in the same boat as one of your questions; make depend isn't found on domd.pl line 30.

Comment: If it helps, I believe `--fipsdir` (or maybe `--fipslibdir`) is the same directory where `fipscanister.o`, `fips_premain.c` and the `*.sha` files are located. It looks like `/my/path/to/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0` may be missing the trailing `lib/`, but I could be wrong. And it does not help that OpenSSL's custom build system is so unusual. It does not follow standard conventions and behaviors. `bash -x` is your friend when attempting to figure out what is going wrong with their tools.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to use the OpenSSL FIPS Module certificate, you MUST follow the steps listed in the user's guide -exactly-.

This is difficult to do within a recipe.  When I've done this, I've always built an SDK and then used the SDK to cross compile the module and OpenSSL program (following the steps in the user's guide -exactly-.)

The I created a patch (bbappend or new recipe) that simply takes the binaries that I previous built and packages them up for others to use.

If you are planning on getting your own certificate, then a lot of this is not necessary.  However, the user's guide steps should still be used as a reference for all of the arguments.

Start with section 4.2 in the user's guide...

Comment: When you say "binaries", did these also include the fipscanister.o? Also, could I ask you to post your openssl's bbappend's do_install function? I've been trying to grok theirs and they seem to install quite a few files. If you don't want to or can't I totally understand.